# Different user levels

Tags: codeigniter

I'm currently working on a new app that will have some different user levels and I'm wondering what the best way is to implement this.

For example we will start with 3 levels:
 1. User (10)
 2. Manager (50)
 3. Boss (100)

I know that all actions the user can do can also be done by the manager and boss, all actions for the manager can be done by the boss.

My first idea was to give each action a name and add it in the database like this:

```
action       |  level
-------------------------
add_user     |  100  (boss only)
login        |  10   (user, manager + boss)
delete_user  |  50   (manager and boss)

$level = 10; // user
if($level >= $actions['add_user']) echo 'allowed';
```

This seems the most flexible way to add new levels in the future, or do you guys have any other suggestions?

Comment: This is the way I've seen it done in some auth libraries. It is very flexible and easily maintained. I'd say go with it. My only suggestion would be to differentiate the levels a bit more: like [user 100], [manager 200], [boss 300] - that way any single or double digit level would not have any access (or at least minimal access), any 100 level would have user actions and below, any 200 level would have manager and below, any 300 level would have all access. This would be easier to follow for me and more intuitive in the controllers.

Comment: @swatkins Thanks, seems like a good idea, would also make it easier to add levels in between.